# Records not matching without LTRIM, RTRIM and Upper/Lower function

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, collation

This issue I am facing from long time. I have two tables in different database having same columns and exactly same data type. But when doing join or any other matching query I get few results only, I noticed that when keeping

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(SourceTable.Column))) =
LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(DestinationTable.Column)))
```

It works fine. I am surprised to say that I have seen same issue on bit and integer column and they also works fine when I keep LTRIM, RTRIM and UPPER/LOWER.

Below are the collation of the two databases:

```
Source: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
Destination: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

As you can see that they have same collation even though I am getting this issue. Can I have a permanent solution to this?

Comment: Um, are you sure you can only join your BIT/INT columns successfully when you use LTRIM/RTRIM/UPPER? That doesn't sound right to me (though I do believe you about the issue on this column). Can you clarify what "exactly same data type" means? Are we talking about char, varchar, nvarchar, etc.? Are the lengths exactly the same? Have you checked the column-level collation as @AdaTheDev has suggested in his answer?

Comment: @Aaron for integer and bit I found that out of 1-3 thousand records, it miss around 20-30 records but when I keep LTRIM and RTRIM it gives me exact results. *Most Important: It does happen 3/10 times* If it happens regulary then I can be sure about the reason.. I am totally confuse about the reason because I think bit and integer should not require ltrim and rtrim

Comment: Could you post your exact table schema of those 2 tables, and your query?

Comment: Also could you explain exactly where you're running these queries? The stuff about bit/integer suffering the same problem makes me believe you're using some tool that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the datatypes are exactly the same, it could be that you actually have a different collation on the columns - you can actually have a different collation to the database one, specified at the column level. First port of call for me would be to check that.

[MSDN resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx), quote:

> Column-level collations
>
> ```
> When you create or alter a table, you can specify collations for each 
> character-string column by using the COLLATE clause. If no collation is 
> specified, the column is assigned the default collation of the database.
> ```

Comment: I have created those tables by creating "create table" script from the destination table and execute the script on source database. There was no collation marked on the column when I created the script, which makes me believe that it has taken the database collation.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite but you can CHECK that instead of just believing it.